# Calling RenderScript from C / JNI

Tags: renderscript

I'm looking to replace the C atan2 function with something more efficient. RenderScript does offer [atan2](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/reference/rs_math.html#android_rs:atan2), including versions that take vectors.

The examples I found, demonstrates calling RenderScript from Java. Is it possible to call RS from C code ? an example would be great.

Thanks

Comment: I think the "more efficient" claim of RenderScript is related to the java performance, not the C performance. If you already program in C, it might well be that atan2 of the C standard library already grants you the best performance.

Comment: @BitTickler the real reason is that I want to move it from the CPU to the GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It used to be possible, though RS support in the NDK has been dropped for some time now.  It may still be possible, but even the NDK samples no longer include RS samples.  Starting with Android 7 you could try to use "Single Source RenderScript", described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html#single-source-rs), which is supposed to be possible from C/C++ code.

The efficiency gains you may see using RS are due to a few possible reasons (which are very platform dependent):

1. RS will parallelize operations over your data set.  In some cases the function you are calling (such as `atan2`) may parallelize the operation, if possible.
2. Your RS code may be executed on a co-processor (such as a GPU or DSP).
3. The RS provided intrinsics and library functions are highly optimized for the platform.  Using `atan2` as an example again, it may be possible that the function is more optimized in the RS core than the standard C library as it could be using a co-processor or it could be using architecture specific optimized implementation (assembly).

All of that being said, your code can take an I/O hit when moving data between RS space (`Allocation`) back to the non-RS code.

Comment: Are there examples of Single Source RenderScript running in C ?

Comment: Larry, does that mean it's likely to stop working in the future?  I'm thinking of switching from Java-called to C-called to better obscure my RS code.  Also want it to work on devices running pre-7.

Comment: I don't know if any single source examples in C, but I've not searched for or created any myself. As for the long term plans for RS support, only Google would know.

Comment: But SingleSource Renderscript will only work in Android 7.0 and above

Answer (score 0):

I have found two examples; here is the one I got to build and run:

https://github.com/adhere/NDKCallRenderScriptDemo

I've been searching for documentation of the C++ API but haven't found it.